# Java Array Traversal Optimization

Tags: java, optimization

I'm currently learning JAVA in a class and we're using the [ACM Graphics package](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/index.html). I wanted some pointers on my code. To provide some context here is the assignment:

> Write a program that creates an array of 5 custom objects (cows, UFOs,
>   cars, etc.) and then lines them up along the left edge of the window.
>   Assign each object a random velocity, and then move the objects to the
>   right edge of the window. When one of the objects (the "winner")
>   reaches the right edge of the window, remove the other objects and
>   cause the winner to flash on and off.

This works just fine and fulfills all the requirements from the assignment. What I want to know is how can I improve this code while still remaining within the requirements. Also any reading materials/videos that you think would be useful for my learning please feel free to share them.

Main Race file:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Race extends GraphicsProgram {

    //Setting up variables
    private static final int WAIT = 20;
    private static final int WINDOWX = 400;
    private static final int WINDOWY = 600;
    private static final int UFO_COUNT = 5;
    private UFO[] ufos = new UFO[UFO_COUNT];
    private boolean flag = true;
    private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();

    public void init() {
        setSize(WINDOWX, WINDOWY);
    }

    public void run() {
        //Set up UFOs at start
        for (int i=0; i<UFO_COUNT; i++) {
            ufos[i] = new UFO(0, i*100);
            ufos[i].alien.setColor(rgen.nextColor());
            add(ufos[i]);
        }

        int winner = -1;
        waitForClick();

        while(flag) {
            pause(WAIT);

            //Move Ufos
            for (int i=0; i<ufos.length; i++ ) {
                ufos[i].move(rgen.nextInt(0, 2), 0);

                //Is there a winner?
                if(ufos[i].getX() > WINDOWX){
                    winner = i;
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!flag) //Safeguard
            displayWinner(winner);
    }

    private void displayWinner(int winner) {
        //Hide others
        for (int i=0; i<ufos.length; i++ ) {
            ufos[i].setVisible(false);
        }

        //Make the winner flash
        while(true) {
            ufos[winner].setVisible(false);
            pause(200);
            ufos[winner].setVisible(true);
            pause(200);
        }
    }
}
```

UFO Constructor Class:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class UFO extends GCompound {    
    public GOval body, bubble, alien;

    public UFO(int x, int y){
        //Draw ufo
        body = new GOval(100, 50);
        body.setFilled(true);
        body.setColor(Color.RED);

        bubble = new GOval(50, 50);
        alien = new GOval(20, 20);
        alien.setFilled(true);
        alien.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        add(bubble, x+26, y+0);
        add(alien, x+40, y+10);
        add(body, x+0, y+26);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Encapsulation

An object's behaviour should be with the object. This means that the UFO should control how it flashes (or blinks):

```
public class UFO ...
  public void blink() {
    setVisible(false);
    pause(200);
    setVisible(true);
    pause(200);
  }

  /** You will have to implement and test this method. */
  private void pause( int milliseconds ) {
    Thread.sleep( milliseconds);
  }
}
```

## Information Hiding

The following code exposes the internals of how a UFO is piloted:

```
ufos[i].alien.setColor(rgen.nextColor());
```

Rather, this should be exposed as an accessor:

```
ufos[i].setPilotColor(rgen.nextColor());
```

Similarly, exposing the UFO's location is not necessary to determine the winner:

```
if(ufos[i].getX() > WINDOWX){
  winner = i;
  flag = false;
}
```

Rather, the above code is more clearly stated as:

```
if(ufos[i].crossedFinishLine( WINDOWX ) ){
  winner = i;
  flag = false;
}
```

Only the UFO need know if it has crossed the finish line. The code is now self-documenting.

Make the following attributes private:

```
public GOval body, bubble, alien;
```

Otherwise your code will be susceptible to [race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458217/why-does-this-code-sometimes-throw-a-nullpointerexception/2458257#2458257) (no pun intended) and be difficult to debug. This is because the UFO class has no control over when its data changes.

## While True

In my [opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420029/how-to-break-out-of-a-loop-from-inside-a-switch/1420100#1420100), `while( true )` is poor form. Instead, add a condition that allows the loop to exit:

```
    while( gameOver() ) {
        ufos[winner].blink();
    }
```

Comment: `UFO` doesn't have a `pause` method.

Comment: Thanks for the pause reference but UFO does have access to the pause method since it's brought in with the import statement at the top. Also great pointers! I read all your links in the answer and wanted to ask if you could elaborate a bit on the `while(true)` part and how I can apply the concept from c++(as in your link) to JAVA.

Comment: Replace `while(true)` with a method that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the loop should continue; all loops should terminate at some point. In the code shown, if `gameOver()` returns true, the winning UFO will blink. If `gameOver()` returns false (because the user has elected to play again or quit the program), then the UFO will stop blinking.

Comment: I get it. It's basically the same as I did with the main race loop where I put a flag in right? Are there any other tips/pointers you would like to add? Also when do I have to use the `this` keyword? Like in your first point you just invoke `setVisible()` without `this`. Is there any case that I would have to use `this`?

Comment: Exactly. (Aside, `flag` could use a more meaningful name.) For `this`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411270/when-should-i-use-this-in-a-class. Some advice: ask questions, be curious, code a lot, read the Pragmatic Programmer (http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer), and devour anything by Martin Fowler (http://martinfowler.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Overall, it looks pretty straightforward.

One thing I would recommend is breaking some of the functions down to smaller functions. Several of the comments in the code scream "move me into a separate function"! Take `displayWinner()` for example. This function does two things, clearly indicated by the comments. Extract those two blocks out into separate functions and call them from `displayWinner()` instead. If the functions are named appropriately, this will also eliminate the need for the comments.

Same thing for the `run()` method.